# PC to PC file transfer over internet

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, file-management, file-sharing

I use a Windows XP PC and have a file of about 700mb, that I would like to copy to another PC (Win XP) over internet. None of the PCs have have a static IP from ISP. How can I transfer the file? I don't prefer uploading the file to a file sharing server and download it in the other PC. Is there any other way (like team viewer or torrent)?

Answer (score 2):

On easy possibility would be using Teamviewer. 
You also could query IP from Websites like http://www.wieistmeineip.de/ but there are many problems with forwarding the adress/port through the router and your firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Skype can also [transfer files](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA3091/how-do-i-send-and-receive-files-using-skype-for-windows-desktop). Probably easier to set up than setting up a ftp server and client.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSH to copy files securely from one system to another. One must run a windows SSH server program such as freeSSHd, while the other uses an SSH copy tool such as PuTTY Secure Copy client. In order to know what your system's IP address is you could write a batch script send an e-mail (with blat) with the server's current IP address, then create a scheduled task to run the script every day (or every few hours even).

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a FTP Server using [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) and connect to it from any other PC/Mac/Smartphone...this is the easiest way to transfer files between your computer over the internet..an alternative would be to use [Dropbox](http://j.mp/mydropboxlink) and put the files in your Public Folder and copy the URL which can then be used to download the file

Comment: Using an FTP server with dynamic IP addresses would be messy since both users would need to confirm the addresses before the upload/download

Comment: A Dynamic DNS like [FreeDNS](http://freedns.afraid.org) can be used which updates the ip address every time it changes

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually ever tried it for a personal files, but you could transfer the file using the [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent) protocol which was designed for peer-to-peer file sharing. There are many free client programs available like [µTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/) to use. The documentation for the latter discusses how to create a private torrent file and send a link to it to someone else for sharing. There are also many tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [[file ai]](http://fileai.com/):

> fileai.com is a free web site that enables people to securely share files with one another that cannot be easily sent via e-mail. You don't need to download or install any software, and your files are not uploaded to any server. The files are encrypted and sent directly, peer-to-peer, through your existing web browser.

Answer (score 0):

[Opera unite](http://unite.opera.com/overview/) used to provide [file sharing](http://unite.opera.com/application/132/) feature from within the opera browser. Pity they are not developing it anymore. Older version might still work.

One suggested alternative is [Tonido's](http://www.tonido.com/index.html) [explorer app](http://www.tonido.com/applications.html) (See [ars tehnica guide](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/09/make-all-your-data-available-on-any-device-no-cloud-required/)).

Obligatory [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/949/) reference.

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer should be the best option(the fastest one) I see imo. Torrent would be very slow to transfer.

Comment: Why would a torrent be any slower?

Comment: That depends on the bandwith between the 2 computers. Torrents and teamviewer have different ways to transfer data.